# printing an image in HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in the web development world and I had the following question

I would like to implement a button in HTML5 that will Print an Image ( and not the whole HTML Page)

I tried the code in this question [Print image on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894428/print-image-on-website)

but I got an unhandled exception :

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error : Umable to get value of the property 'innerHTML':object is null or undefined
```

can anyone guide me how to do this ?

Thanks!

Edit : When I say print , I mean prininting on a physical printer , and not displaying on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is the very simple way of doing it :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="showimage()">Click Here for Image</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showimage() {
     if (typeof img== 'object')
                    img= img.src;
                window.win = open(img);
                setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("Print")', 500);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I whipped this up

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="showimage()">Click Here for Image</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showimage() {
    var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    //you can replace the link with any image you want
    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://i.123g.us/c/cute_teddy/card/109882.gif');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'Picture');
    _body.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EKPsA/)

If you need help understanding how this works, don't hesitate to ask. Basically, we have a button and we create the img tag and set the appropriate attributes. Once we have successfully done that, we can then append it to the body of the HTML document so it displays. I suggest you get a good understanding of the DOM (Document Object Model) since you are new to web development/Javascript.

Comment: thank you @aug for your response!
I tried the code and it works!. it is just that it is not what I need to do . When I say print I meant printing on a physical printer (and not displaying it on the screen). Sorry for the confusion